# How to Create Multiple Columns in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns

I trying to create a multiple column layout with different sizes in bootstrap, but I can't figure it out.  The columns should be responsive to all mobiles and tablet screen sizes.

Please refer to [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSvbk.png).

Comment: You haven't said *how* it should act responsively. You need to specify what it should look like on smaller screens too.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you for reminding , I want it to be responsive to (( small , medium and large devices ))  !!  Thanks

Comment: That answer is useless. Let me clarify: You have not showed us how the divs should be laid out on the other (smaller) screen sizes.

Comment: Yes , give me few minutes to draw the layout , the way I want it to be displayed . Thank you

Comment: **Please have a look** >> https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5za-Wfvmxv2TjdKTWg4azVTMkE/edit?usp=docslist_api <<>> so basically for the small devices even if it shown as multiple rows I don't mind !!

Comment: Also this one please >> https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5za-Wfvmxv2T2dSWjVhNlVobFU/edit?usp=docslist_api